# Wireless earbuds for single sided deafness

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, earphones

I'm looking for wireless earbuds which are reversible and can be used individually.

I can only hear in one of my ears and therefore getting earbuds which are not reversible is just extra junk for me. I'm just looking for a decent pair, price is not a concern to me.

I'd like for them to be able to be used one at a time (like this I can double my battery life).

Also, I need them to be able to be reversible (right bud in left ear or vice versa) - at least to an extent, meaning if I have to flip them, that's not a huge deal, but with these giant earbuds, they usually need to be in the correct ear in order to help support their weight and flipping them wouldn't work.

I saw some from Rowkin, as they seem to be the right shape, I'm not sure if they can be used individually though. Also they have mediocre reviews (on all models) with lots of customers complaining about battery etc.

[image: Rowkin]

I also just found the Nokia True Wireless buds;

[image: Nokia]

Again, limited reviews and no indication if they can be used individually.

Comment: What devices would you be using them with? If it is mobile or a computer, you can probably use either earbud on its own by adjusting the "Balance" in your sound settings. That would simplify your search to just finding a set with the right the physical shape.